# How to run all the unit-tests of the TestClass together with its inner TestClass tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have inner classes to unit-test instance methods like below.

My problem is when I go to `FooClassTests` and use VS to run all tests in context, it skips the inner class tests.

If you are using this structure, do you know how can I run all tests together with the ones in the inner classes?

```
[TestClass]
public class FooClassTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void CanGuardConstructorParameters()
    {
        // Asserts here
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class DoWorkTests //Tests method DoWork
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanDoTheWork()
        {
            // Asserts here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using inner Test Classes?

Comment: Because 
1) I do not want to repeat the name of test in all my unit test methods,
2) It helps me to group all tests per method in a particular inner class,
3) Easier to rename one class that renaming all unit-tests methods, in case I rename the method under test.

Comment: @Erno It becomes much easier to manage a large suite of tests doing this. This is especially true when you are using your tests as documentation, by having one class per method you can specify all the invalid assertions as well as the valid ones. If you return custom exceptions you can provide a set of tests that show how to handle these without cluttering up your main testing class.

Comment: @pencilCake It might be an idea to say which test framework you are using as it may be a limitation of the test runner when analysing your tests.

Comment: @Erno No bother, see the link below, it links to a post about it as well as another one by Phil Haack which explains this sort of testing in a bit more detail.

Comment: Yes, I read it. I also did a little test and found that the exact location where you right-click in the test classes is very important. I would like to be able to right-click a method and run its unit test but that doesn't seem te work.

Comment: I have the same problem with two different test class (that are not embedded). Have you found a way to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via Visual Studio Runner I don't know but this is supported in NCrunch. This is how I structure all my tests.

See http://www.ncrunch.net/

This guy seems to be using it fine in MS Test too:

http://zendeveloper.blogspot.ie/2012/01/structuring-unit-tests.html

And I am almost certain that these type of tests work in resharper's test runner.

Comment: The second link helped me.

Comment: Great, Yeah I didn't realise NCrunch has gone commerical which doesn't make it a viable product for many.